# ggmap in R - keep google copyright information on cropped map

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap

I was wondering if anyone knows how to keep the google copyright information on maps plotted (with a new scale) by ggmap in R?

For example:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

# download basemap
ggmap::register_google(key="xxx") # insert your hey here xxx
ggmap::ggmap_show_api_key()
base_map <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon= -2.325278, lat=54.6000000), zoom = 5, style = 'element:labels|visibility:off',color= "bw")
```

When I plot `base_map` without changing the scale the copyright information is inserted at the bottom of the plot as so:

```
ggmap(base_map, extent = "panel")
```

[image: map_with_copyright_info)]

However, when I plot `base_map` with a new `x` and `y axis` to zoom into mainland Britain. I also crop off the copyright info. As below:

```
ggmap(base_map, extent = "panel")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-7, 3), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(49.5, 59), expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image: map_zoom_noCopyright]

Does anyone know how I can get the second plot but with the copyright information that I need for publication?

I have tried to change the `zoom=` argument in the `get_googlemap()` function but it always seems to either cut the top or bottom off the UK and I need to be able to see the whole area for when I plot my data.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used a lot ggmap, and this type of problem I could not solve then in an elegant way. But there is a way to achieve something like what you want (doing kind of manually). With `geom_rect` making the lightbox, and with `geom_text` writing the copyright information.

```
ggmap(base_map, extent = "panel")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-7, 3), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(49.5, 59), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_rect(ymin = 49.5,ymax = 49.7, fill = 'white', alpha = 0.1, xmin = -3.35, xmax = 3) +
  geom_text(y = 49.6, x = -0.2, size = 2.5,
             label = 'Map data ©2020 GeoBasis-DE/BKG (©2009), Google, Inst. Geogr Nacional') 
ggsave('Map.jpg', width = 7, height = 9, units = 'in')
```

The size and limits of `geom_rect` and `geom_text` must be edited manually according to the size of the save file. In this example, I provide the `ggsave` I used for it and plot in a nice way.

Comment: Thank you for this :) I have accepted this as the answer as I can use the exact crop of the map I was after.

Answer (score 8):

Although seemingly simple, this is actually a quite complex issue. I did some research and found out that you can achieve this by tweaking both `size` and `scale` arguments. However, if you are using `ggmap` v3.0.0 as I do, you will find that specifying non-square dimensions just gives you a "noisy image" as follows:

```
base_map <- ggmap::get_googlemap(center = c(lon= -2.325278, lat=54.6000000), zoom = 5, size = c(331, 367), style = 'element:labels|visibility:off', color= "bw")
ggmap(base_map, extent = "panel")
```

[image: noisy map]

This involves a known [bug](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/17) in the `ggmap` package. It has not yet been resolved. Although there exists a solution as mentioned [here](https://github.com/lorenzwalthert/ggmap/commit/c6b68ebbb02929b4d628410bfbd0fdff32ac3152), that only partially solves the problem because the solution has failed for some cases mentioned in this [post](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/245).  Hence, I'd suggest rewriting that function to make it work in a robust way. Luckily, after investigating the source code, I found the problem not so hard to deal with. The problem results from some image-processing failure in the `get_goolemap` function. Therefore, outsourcing the image processing in that function to a dedicated package is a simple workaround.

Consider this `get_googlemap2` (to make it simple, I have ignored all those argument checkings in the original `get_goolemap`, so be careful with your inputs)

```
require(RgoogleMaps)
require(httr)
require(magick)
require(urltools)
require(tibble)

get_googlemap2 <- function(
  api_key = "Your API Key", 
  center = c(lon = -95.3632715, lat = 29.7632836), 
  zoom = 10, size = c(640, 640), scale = 2, 
  maptype = c("terrain", "satellite", "roadmap", "hybrid"), 
  grayscale = FALSE, style
) {
  maptype <- match.arg(maptype)
  
  params <- c(
    center = paste0(center[c(2L, 1L)], collapse = ","), 
    zoom = zoom, 
    size = paste0(size, collapse = "x"), 
    scale = scale, 
    maptype = maptype, 
    style = style, 
    key = api_key
  )
  url <- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap"
  urltools::parameters(url) <- paste(names(params), params, sep = "=", collapse = "&")
  url <- URLencode(url)
  
  message("Souce: ", url)
  img <- magick::image_read(httr::content(httr::GET(url)))
  if (grayscale) img <- magick::image_quantize(img, colorspace = "gray")
  ll <- RgoogleMaps::XY2LatLon(
    list(lat = center[2], lon = center[1], zoom = zoom),
    -size[1]/2 + 0.5, -size[2]/2 - 0.5
  )
  ur <- RgoogleMaps::XY2LatLon(
    list(lat = center[2], lon = center[1], zoom = zoom),
    size[1]/2 + 0.5, size[2]/2 - 0.5
  )
  structure(
    as.raster(img), class = c("ggmap", "raster"),
    source = "google", maptype = maptype, zoom = zoom,
    bb = tibble::tibble(ll.lat = ll[1], ll.lon = ll[2], ur.lat = ur[1], ur.lon = ur[2])
  )
}
```

I tried some specifications of `size` and `scale` with this new function and found out that the following specifications render the best map possible.

```
base_map <- get_googlemap2(
  "Your API Key", 
  center = c(lon = -2.325278, lat = 54.6000000), zoom = 5, size = c(330, 380), scale = 2, style = 'element:labels|visibility:off', grayscale = TRUE
)
ggmap(base_map, extent = "panel")
```

Output

[image: final_image]

I hope this is what you want. I call this the best-possible result because if you attempt to further narrow the width, for example, down to 250, the attribution text will overlap with the logo.

```
base_map <- get_googlemap2(
  "Your API Key", 
  center = c(lon = -2.325278, lat = 54.6000000), zoom = 5, size = c(250, 380), scale = 2, style = 'element:labels|visibility:off', grayscale = TRUE
)
ggmap(base_map, extent = "panel")
```

[image: overlap]

As far as I can tell, this is Google's problem, not `ggmap`'s. I have no way to solve it. Another workaround would be removing the attribution text from the image but reintroducing it as plain text within the content, as mentioned in Google's [attribution guidlines](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide/). However, as Google's logo still needs to be there, you then have to figure out how to paste that onto the map. IMO, using plain text gives you greater flexibility in page layouts, and thus might be a better way to go.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer :D I seem to get an error when I run the `get_googlemap2()` function? It is as follows: 
```Error in tibble(ll.lat = ll[1], ll.lon = ll[2], ur.lat = ur[1], ur.lon = ur[2]) : 
  could not find function "tibble"
Called from: structure(as.raster(img), class = c("ggmap", "raster"), 
    source = "google", maptype = maptype, zoom = zoom, 
    bb = tibble(ll.lat = ll[1], ll.lon = ll[2], ur.lat = ur[1], 
        ur.lon = ur[2]))```

Comment: Sorry, missed out this `require(tibble)` @QPaps

Comment: I have accepted the answer above as it allows me to use the exact crop of the map that I was looking for. However your answer (which I have also upvoted) has been very useful and I am sure will be useful in the future - so thank you again :)